# Getting :&quot; when converting Json object to XML in Java

Tags: java, json, xml

Im trying to convert JsonObject to XML but it seems to be encored.

This is my JsonObject -

```
{
  "customerName": "cus1",
  "invoiceNumber": "in1",
  "invoiceDate": "2017-01-23",
  "amount": 110.1,
  "invoiceItems": [
    {
      "chargeName": "null",
      "subscriptionName": "TestSub",
      "amount": 129,
      "servicePeriod": "2017-01-23to 2017-02-23"
    },
    {
      "subscriptionName": "",
      "servicePeriod": "",
      "chargeDate": "",
      "chargeName": "Discounted Amount",
      "amount": -12.9
    }
  ]
}
```

Output I'm getting is  -

```
{&quot;customerName&quot;:&quot;cus1;,&quot;invoiceNumber&quot;:&quot;in1;,&quot;invoiceDate&quot;:&quot;2017-01-23&quot;,&quot;amount&quot;:116.1,&quot;invoiceItems&quot;:[{&quot;chargeName&quot;:&quot;null&quot;,&quot;subscriptionName&quot;:&quot;TestSubd&quot;,&quot;amount&quot;:129.0,&quot;servicePeriod&quot;:&quot;2017-01-23to 2017-02-23&quot;},{&quot;subscriptionName&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;servicePeriod&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;chargeDate&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;chargeName&quot;:&quot;Discounted Amount&quot;,&quot;amount&quot;:-12.9}]}"
```

Output im expecting is without encoding `<customerName>cus1<customerName>` format.

I have used `org.json.XML` to convert the json object to xml

```
  JsonObject invoiceDetailObj = new JsonObject();
invoiceDetailObj.addProperty("customerName", aa.get("customer").asText());
```

I added properties to the invoiceDetailObj so that its currently looks like the jsonObj I have added in the top

```
 xml = XML.toString(invoiceDetailObj);
```

Comment: please provide more code (we dont know what is `invoiceDetailObj`, for example: `String`? `JSONObject` ?)

Comment: Nop invoiceDetails obj is  - JsonObject invoiceDetailObj = new JsonObject(); I have added more data and its like the one shown.

Comment: How the `{"customerName": "cus1", ...}` is put into the `invoiceDetailObj`?

Comment: invoiceDetailObj.addProperty("customerName", aa.get("customer").asText());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is related to the fact that you mix `com.google.gson.JsonObject` from [**Google Gson**](https://github.com/google/gson) with `org.json.JSONObject`. Actually, the method `XML.toString(object)` expects an instance of `org.json.JSONObject` or `org.json.JSONArray` or an array of `org.json.JSONObject` so what you get is simply the default behavior of this method when none of those types are found.

Simply rewrite your code to use `org.json.JSONObject` instead of `com.google.gson.JsonObject`, your code should then look like something like this:

```
JSONObject invoiceDetailObj = new JSONObject();
invoiceDetailObj.put("customerName", "cus1");
invoiceDetailObj.put("invoiceNumber", "in1");
...
String xml = XML.toString(invoiceDetailObj);
```

Or even better, if you have your `JSON` object as a `String`, you could simply use the constructor `JSONObject(String source)` to let it parse and build the `JSONObject` for you:

```
String xml = XML.toString(new JSONObject(myJSONString));
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed the issue